# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '55100,63622' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am passing to a stored procedure values such as '55100,63622', these are placed in a variable `@StaffList NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Then I try to use these two numbers in a select, then insert them into a temp table. I get the following error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '55100,63622' to data type int.

```
INSERT INTO #Staff (StaffId, Forename, Surname)
SELECT AutoID, Forename, Surname
FROM tblUserData WHERE AutoID in (@StaffList)
```

I am wondering how I can pass the '55100,63622' as a string to the stored procedure, and use in a select statement? Would be better to change the string to OR statements, 'AutoID = 55100 OR AutoID = 6322'

Comment: If you know there are two values, then the `OR` is better.

Comment: You can't pass one variable to `in` and have it parse it as a list. You could do `WHERE AutoID in (@Staff1, @Staff2)` and pass them separately.

Comment: The idea would be send through a string of multiple id's, could I split the values in the stored procedure?

Comment: If I sent through a string of multiple OR conditions: 'AutoID = 55100 OR AutoID = 6322 OR AutoID = 111'. Would this be better?

Comment: Please read http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings and http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a split function to split the comma separated values into rows and then use that in the where clause. see the sample below

```
INSERT INTO #Staff (StaffId, Forename, Surname)
SELECT AutoID, Forename, Surname
FROM tblUserData WHERE AutoID in (select * from dbo.split(@StaffList,','))
```

split function sample

```
  CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: [Multi-statement TVF is probably the least efficient way to split a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704767/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-nvarchar-value-55100-63622-to-data-type#comment53253515_32704767).

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. There's no graceful way to convert the string to a table, but for brute force. How you use it after that (store values in a table variable for MSSQl) vs repeatedly splitting the string is where your performance would be hit. That being said, please feel free to improve on it so we can all benefit.

Answer (score 1):

A field with '55100,63622' is a **multivaluated field**. Your data is not in firts normal form. **You should avoid to store several values in a field designed to store just one.**

You should to pas two values @staf1, @staf2:

```
AutoId in ( @staf1, @staf2 )
```

If you have a variable number of parameters I suggest to you to pass an XML as parameter and join it in your select.

Search about xml parameter or xml join. Some sample:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters

Also, SQL Server 2008 and newer, you have table-valued parameters:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Both structures are intended to store more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

Your in statement around @StaffList should be a table. We have a function called SPLIT that returns a table, so the where clause would look like

```
... where AutoID in (Select * from dbo.SPLIT(@StaffList,','))
```

Here is a split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
@ItemList VARCHAR(max), 
@delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @IDTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(36))  
AS      

BEGIN    
DECLARE @tempItemList VARCHAR(max)
SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

DECLARE @i INT    
DECLARE @Item VARCHAR(max)

SET @tempItemList = REPLACE (@tempItemList, ' ', '')
SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
BEGIN
    IF @i = 0
        SET @Item = @tempItemList
    ELSE
        SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
    INSERT INTO @IDTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
    IF @i = 0
        SET @tempItemList = ''
    ELSE
        SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
END 
RETURN
```

END

Comment: [Multi-statement TVF is probably the least efficient way to split a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704767/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-nvarchar-value-55100-63622-to-data-type#comment53253515_32704767).